# How do I prove this? (Set Theory, Mathematical Logic)

Tags: logic, set-theory, solution-verification, peano-axioms

I'm studying for an exam of mathematical logic.
This question envolves the Peano axioms, I think.

Prove that, for all $ n \in \omega$, $ n \notin n$.

It's kind of obvious that it's true but I don't know how to prove it.
I tried to assume that $ n \in n$ and the first element $0 \in 0$ is false but honestly it doesn't seem right to do this. If I go with $ n \notin n$, a set is never an element of itself so it seems irrelevant to go further.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Ok, so from what I've seen from Von Neumann ordinals I know the following:

1. $ 0 \in \omega$ and thus $0 \notin 0$ because $ 0 = \{ \}$ and $ 0 \notin \{ \}$
2. $n \in \omega$ and thus $n^+ \in w$ with $ n^+ = n$ $\cup$ $\{n \}$

Now, if $n \notin n$ then $n^+ \notin n^+$ right?

If I assume that $ n^+ \in n^+$ is true, can I say that, since $ n^+ = n$ $\cup$ $\{n \}$, then $ n^+ = n$ or $ n^+ \in \{n\}$? And then claim this is absurd?

Comment: What is [$n$ in set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Von_Neumann_ordinals) ?

Comment: I guess the @vcraft is refering to this construction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Constructions_based_on_set_theory

Comment: @jon.sand: That would also explain the unexplained $w$; it probably is meant to be $\omega$.

Comment: Yes, it's meant to be $\omega$. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Does even Peano arithmetics have $\in$ relation? I think it doesn't. It is a general statement that $x\notin x$ for all $x$. In ZFC its proof would look like this:
Set $S=\{y\in x\colon y=x\}$, if it's nonempty then by regularity axiom there is $z\in S$ such that $z\cap S=\emptyset$ but $z\cap S=x\cap S\supset S$, contradiction. If $S$ is empty then we are also done.

Comment: Well, I thought it was related to Peano because of the construction of it but Von Neumann ordinals seem to fit better here. 
So, I would like to reach the proof with one of these constructions, if possible.

Comment: My proof is general, I proved a statement about any set $x$. As Von Neumann ordinals are within the ZF, so this proof is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've been seeing the Von Neumann ordinals and I updated my question. Can you review it and tell me what you think? It's not complete and I didn't actually reach a false statement, I just think it's false.

Comment: If you really want to prove it from this point of view, then your proof is more less right, but you have to put on this some "formal" mathematical induction: 1) $0\notin 0$ is clear, since we can "write" $0$ down, next step is: assume that $n\notin n$ for some $n\in\omega$, so if $n^+\in n^+$ then... and here comes rest of your proof, but the last thing is not $n^+\in\{n\}$ but $n^+\in n$ and you should explain why it can't happen.

Comment: I think I'm missing something important and I'm not sure what it is. For example, do we need statement $\forall n\in\omega~ n\notin n$ to prove mathematical induction? It might be possible, if so, then this way of proving is pointless. As I said before, in construction of $\omega$ we are using regularity axiom (correct me if I'm wrong), even if not explicitly, and $\forall x~x\notin x$ is almost direct consequence of it, so....

Comment: Ok, great! So I get to the point where $ n^+ \in n $ and $ n^+ = n$ but how can I explain that it can't happen? For the first I thought of stating that $ n \in n^+ \in n$ thus $ n \in n$ which is false because, like you said, we should assume $ n \notin n$. But for $ n \in n^+ = n$ I get that $n = n$ which is true I guess. What's wrong in this last one?

Comment: For the second, its obvious, since you can just point at different elements. As for your answer for the first it's ok, but note that you are using that $\in$ relation is transitive, which is not true in general, but is true in case of any ordinals and to prove that it is true, you have to use regularity axiom... so once again we are in vicious circle.

Comment: Ok,  I must correct myself, $n\in n^+$ is just by construction, not by transitivity on ordinals.

Comment: I don't get it despite it being obvious, I'm still new at this. If $ n \in n^+ = n$, how do I get from $ n = n$ to $ n \in n$ so I can say that it's false? Or do I say that $ n = n$ is false? Because it's supposed to be true I guess. I'm insisting on this because I have to do it with these constructions, sorry..

Edit: I just got it! It's obvious cause if $ n^+ = n$ and $ n \in n^+$ then of course that $ n \in n$. Well, that does it. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: And by the way, I'm really grateful for your time! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @pem You don't need regularity for any of this (not to prove the statement, nor to prove a natural number is a transitive set). And as such, using regularity somewhat misses the point.

Comment: To add on the comment by @spaceisdarkgreen, the statement of this exercise hints that it was introduced before a discussion on the axiom of regularity (which may or may not happen at all).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen so how do you define $\omega$? What I mean is that I think you need machinery of ordinal numbers to prove existence and uniqueness of $\omega$, and in ordinals you need regularity axiom. But I don't have any book on set theory right now and just don't care about checking it. Existence of inductive set is given by axiom, but I think we need to take intersection of all its inductive subsets and then using linearity of ordering on ordinals prove uniqueness (independence of choosing our first inductive set).

Comment: @pem You define it like you said, but you don't need regularity for the ordinals or to prove any basic facts about them. See Kunen or Jech... in both books the theory of the ordinals is developed before regularity is introduced. Good rule of thumb is that regularity is not needed for anything useful for 'ordinary mathematics'. It is necessary for some fundamental facts pertaining to the ordinals, but only very set-theory-specific things, e.g. to show that the ordinals are absolute for transitive models.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen ok, then, I believe you, my memory failed then :)